# Error using Authentication in ASP .NET CORE WITH EFCORE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.0

Net Core( ASP.Net in general) I have followed the series of online tutorial and met with this error after using EF (DB first) with ASP.NET core.

If i run it, I get this

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>   Generated Code
>   One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.
>   The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
>   The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>     [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"9a0db165e84c12ef1478a3e118ff09ac424c3083", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
>   The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"8868ba9fecd1b49833b2cca21afdef560734f417", @"/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml")]
>   Show compilation source"

After uninstalling Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design from Package Manager Console.

It runs fine but when trying to add a new controller...I get this error

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations..ctor
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.IOperationsReporter,
>   System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Reflection.Assembly)'.'"

Comment: Please Help. i am the latest Visual Studio 2017..Sorry Cant post images as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you running? CodeGen was rolled into 2.1. In addition to removing the NuGet, you should edit your project(s) and ensure that it's not included via `DotNetCliToolReference`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt , but the issue is I wont be able to add a controller with Ef if i remove the package..Is there a way out??

Comment: You misunderstand. In 2.1, that's built-in. You don't need the package or the tools reference. Assuming you're running 2.1, which you haven't confirmed but seems likely, the problems you're experiencing now is directly due to including the old CodeGen tool. Once all vestiges are gone, the 2.1 code gen will take over.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisPratt, That seems to work now with the new Visual Studio update released today as it targeted the.Net Core 2.1 directly and form your advice I didn't need to install codeGen.Cheers

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisPratt, faced the same issue while adding codeGen tool explicitly, which wasn`t needed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when I followed Tutorial for Pagination, I installed MvcPagedList.Core but i think it installed .net core 1.1 libraries.
I changed Target framework to 2.1 and updated following packages to latest version

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
- Microsoft.NETCore.App

Cleaned and ran project without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the version of you Microsoft libraries you have added to your project. If you are using 2.1.0 version of Microsoft libraries be consistence with that version for all the libraries. I had the same issue and that approach solved it.